# Python - Can't subprocess.call after os.fork()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, fork, openwrt

I have a forked python process which need to execute another python script.
I am using python 2.7 in OpenWRT.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./twitter.py", line 61, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['./tweet.py', text])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
```

Here's how i fork the process:

```
try:
pid = os.fork()
print pid
if pid > 0:
    # Exit parent process
    sys.exit(0)
except OSError, e:
    self.logger("Fork failed")
    sys.exit(1)
```

And here's how I try to call another script:

```
subprocess.call(['./tweet.py', text])
```

Comment: You are missing an interesting part of the traceback: The exception itself. Please add that! Also, use code formatting (`` ``` `` or indentation) for the tracebacks instead of blockquotes (``>``) for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This error is saying that Python can't find the file `./tweet.py`.
By default, Python looks in the current working directory, i.e. the directory from which the script was *called*. Note that this may not be the same as the directory in which the script is located.

Try supplying an absolute path, or using `os.chdir` to change to the directory containing `tweet.py`, or constructing the path based on its relationship to `__file__`, the path of the calling script. For example, if `tweet.py` is in the same directory as the calling script, you could use:

```
tweetpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tweet.py')
subprocess.call([tweetpath, text])
```